# onActivityResult is deprecated in android 13

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-account, huawei-iap

As Android framework update, `onActivityResult` method going to be deprecated.

Doc: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

However, in the Huawei account & IAP SDK, we are still using `onActivityResult` in a lot of places to give task results to developers, do we have a plan to replace them?

If so, when could we expect a new Huawei SDK with this change?

Thank you.